# How to generate oauth signture in python

Tags: python-2.7, oauth, odoo, odoo-8

import oauth

http://developer.pesapal.com/how-to-integrate/api-reference#PostPesapalDirectOrderV4

I am doing integration with pesapal. Pesapal required oauth signature how to generate correct signature

I am facing this error on pesapal site: Problem: signature_invalid | Advice: > |

Answer (score 0):

I am provide you one link of github

https://github.com/kelonye/python-pesapal

This Example may be help you.

and Onther Example Code of pesapal API

https://github.com/okal/pesapal.py/tree/master/pesapal